# change value of iframe's element

Tags: jquery, iframe, set

I got an iframe that i use to upload a file to my server. I want to pass to the iframe the name i want for the file, but i haven't been able to do it.

I got this content in my iframe:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="idProductoFormUpload" id="idProductoFormUpload"    value="test">    
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

code of the iframe element:

```
<iframe id="iframeUpload" name="iframeUpload" src="uploadForm.html" style="height:100px;"></iframe>
```

All i want to do is set the value for the 'idProductoFormUpload' input.

I tried this with no success:

```
$('#iframeUpload').contents().find('#idProductoFormUpload').val('myValue');
```

Comment: I test that code and works, can you show all the html you have? Are you closing the body and html tags?

Comment: Yes i do, just that i missed it when i copied it here. If this code works for you it should do it for me aswell. I will check my code again and try to find the error.  Thnks !!

Comment: Anyway, is there another way to do something similar ?? to pass an id to the iframe ??

Answer (score 5):

Your code is good. I often ran into this problem too. Make sure you put the javascript AFTER the iframe.

Comment: Put this is a onload event called from the iframe